# Product $\sigma$-algebra of power sets

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory, natural-numbers

Let $X,Y$ be any two sets. In general, what is the product $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{P}(X) \times \mathcal{P}(Y)$? In the context (using Fubini's Theorem to prove that one can reverse the order of summation for absolutely convergent double series) the author makes an implicit assumption that, at least in the case $X=Y=\mathbb{N}$, we have $\mathcal{P}(X) \times \mathcal{P}(Y)=\mathcal{P}(X \times Y)$. But I do not see why is this true or in what cases it holds. Here it seems that every subset of $\mathbb{N}^2$ must somehow be a union (possibly with complements) of Cartesian products of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: In the special case mentioned, every subset of $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ must be a countable union of singleton sets $\{ (m_0, n_0) \} = \{ m_0 \} \times \{ n_0 \}$.

Comment: Of course, a silly oversight...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot show that $\mathcal{P}(X \times Y) = \mathcal{P}(X) \times \mathcal{P}(Y)$, and this is not what your author claims.

For countable $X$ and $Y$, the sigma-algebra generated by all sets $A \times B$, where $A \in \mathcal{P}(X)$ and $B \in \mathcal{P}(Y)$ contains all singletons $\{(x,y)\} = \{x\} \times \{y\}$ and thus all subsets of the countable set $X \times Y$, so the *generated sigma-algebra* for the product is indeed $\mathcal{P}(X \times Y)$.

This no longer holds for *uncountable* sets though. In that case it's a classic fact that the diagonal $D= \{(x,x): x \in X\}$ is not in the generated sigma-algebra by $\mathcal{P}(X) \times \mathcal{P}(X)$ when $|X| > \mathfrak{c}$ (see [Nedoma's pathology](https://www.drmaciver.com/2006/04/journal-of-obscure-results-1-nedomas-pathology/)), so we generate a proper sub-sigma-algebra of $\mathcal{P}(X \times Y)$. For $|X| =\aleph_1$ we do get the desired result. (due to V. Rao.) Daniel Schepler (in the comments below) shows that this also extends to sets of size $\mathfrak{c}$, so we have a division of uncountable sizes here: small uncountable (where we do get $\mathbb{P}(X \times Y) = \mathcal{P}(X) \otimes \mathcal{P}(Y)$) and large uncountable where this fails to be the case. The countable case is straightforward, as we saw.

Comment: Not sure if it was clear enough (although I did say this in the first sentence and imply it in the last), but when I refer to $\mathcal{P}(X) \times \mathcal{P}(Y)$, I mean the product $\sigma$-algebra generated by those $\sigma$-algebras, not just the usual Cartesian product. The (trivial) countable case is clear now, but I don't quite understand the argument for the uncountable case. If it is complicated could you provide a link to a proof?

Comment: The diagonal is actually in the product $\sigma$-algebra also for $\mathbb{R}$ - but it's not in the product $\sigma$-algebra if $|X| > \mathfrak{c}$.  e.g. if $X$ is the set of sequences $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ then for each $n$, $\{ x \mid (x_1)_n = (x_2)_n \}$ is a countable union of products, and then the countable intersection of these sets is the diagonal.

Comment: @DanielSchepler I know it for $\aleph_1$, what is the reference for $\mathbb{R}$? without CH of course....

Comment: I already showed the diagonal is in the product $\sigma$-algebra in the case $X = \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ which is bijective with $\mathbb{R}$.  A possible proof that the diagonal isn't in the product $\sigma$-algebra if $|X| > \mathfrak{c}$ is that the subsets of $X \times X$ with at most $\mathfrak{c}$ distinct "vertical fibers" form a $\sigma$-algebra containing product sets - using the fact that $\mathfrak{c}^{\aleph_0} = \mathfrak{c}$.

Comment: Also, the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ already contains the diagonal and it's certainly contained in the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}) \times \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$.  (Unfolding this proof a bit gets to essentially the proof I presented for $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$.)

Comment: @DanielSchepler the Borel case for the reals is easier as then we’re dealing with countably generated sigma-algebras. And the complement of the diagonal is a countable union of open rectangles by hereditary Lindelöfness, etc.

Comment: I guess the thing for me to take away from this is that the uncountable case was a lot more complicated than I expected...

Comment: @AlephNull it is, so up to size of the reals is OK, above it fails (and I included a link to a possible proof and Daniel also sketched an alternative).

Answer (score 0):

It's about $\sigma$-algebras.

Take any $R\subset \mathcal P(\mathbb N\times\mathbb N)$. Define 
$$
R^x=\{y\in\mathbb N:\ (x,y)\in R\}.
$$
Then 
$$
R=\bigcup_{x\in\mathbb N} \{x\}\times R^x.
$$
As each of the sets $\{x\}\times R^x\in\mathcal P(\mathbb N)\times \mathcal P(\mathbb N)$, their (countable) union is in the $\sigma$-algebra they generate. Thus the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $ \mathcal P(\mathbb N)\times \mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ is $ \mathcal P(\mathbb N\times\mathbb N)$.